# TTIWDBAdvWebGrid & controller paging, how to get ctDynEdit cells to also page?

Tags: delphi, intraweb, tms

My Delphi/Intraweb application uses a TMS TTIWDBAdvWebGrid associated with a dynamically created TClientDataSet via a TDatasource component. The idea is to allow a user to page through a large amount of records using the controller, and optionally enter values in the last DynEdit column. The paging works fine for all columns, aside from the single DynEdit column which appears static. For example, if I enter a value in any DynEdit field, and click "next" on the controller, the page does correctly show the next page of records, but the DynEdit column still shows the same edited values of the previous page. What is frustrating is that it did work a week ago, but since then I must have accidentally changed something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused because I had the Intraweb form's UpdateMode property set to umPartial, and TTIWDBAdvWebGrid.AsynchPaging set to true.

With the form's UpdateMode set to umAll and TTIWDBAdvWebGrid.AsynchPaging disabled, it works as expected.